# How to make an async call inside other async call with a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I really want to improve and understand how to do this better. This code is working, but I believe there is something wrong here. The idea is the following:

1: I make the first HTTP call to the API and I get the data.

2: the data I use is matchHistoryArr that has an array of 10 "gameIds" and I need to pass them through a forEach(loop) to this.summ.getMatches(gameId) and push them to a new local array needed to compare with another array to sort it(because async doesn't give it sorted) so after searching a lot I could solve it like this. (I'm going to mark in the code)
**note**: this is the place where I had a big problem,

3: Now I need to get more data from other endpoints, but I believe I have to order the code better before continuing.

**Component.ts**

```
     onSubmit(){
** 1 **
    this.summ.getSummoner(this.summoner.name,this.summoner.regionId)
    .subscribe(  (data:any) => {

      let matchHistoryArr = data.matchHistory

      let gameIdArray = matchHistoryArr.map( element => element.gameId)

      const subscribers: Subscriber<any>[] = [];
        const promiseMatchesArray = [];

** 2 **
       matchHistoryArr.forEach( element => {

         promiseMatchesArray.push( this.summ.getMatches(element.gameId).toPromise().then( match => {

           subscribers.push(match)
         }));
         });

           Promise.all(promiseMatchesArray).then( a =>{
               if ( subscribers.length === matchHistoryArr.length ){

                let arraySort = [];
                arraySort = subscribers
                let dataParticipants

                  let matchesArraySorted = arraySort.sort((a, b) => {  
                   return gameIdArray.indexOf(a.gameId) - gameIdArray.indexOf(b.gameId);
                 });

                 this.matchesArray = matchesArraySorted

                 matchesArraySorted.forEach( x => {

                  dataParticipants = x.participants
                  });

                  if ( dataParticipants.length === 10 ){

                    this.dataParticipants = dataParticipants
                  }
               }
           });


      this.matchHistory = matchHistoryArr
      this.SummInfo = data.summonerdata;

     });

  }
```

**Services.ts**

```
export class SummonerService {

  constructor( private http:HttpClient ) { }

  summonerName

    getSummoner(summonerName,regionId){
    this.summonerName = summonerName
   return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/summName/${summonerName}/${regionId}` )
   .pipe(
    map( (data:any) => data)
   )};



   getChampImage(champId){
     return this.http.get(`https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/plugins/rcp-be-lol-game-data/global/default/v1/champion-icons/${champId}.png`)
   };

   getMatches(gameId){
     return this.http.get( `http://localhost:3000/match/${gameId}` )
     .pipe( 
       map( (data:any) => this.uploadData(data))
       )};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, your example can be boiled down to two steps:

1. Get data from observable
2. Perform set of calls based on data from 1.

I would recommend sticking to observables all the way through, unless there is a compelling reason to use promises.

1. Make the initial call as you are doing
   1a. Switch to new observable using `concatMap`
2. Create array of observables and run in parallel using `forkJoin`

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.summ.getSummoner(this.summoner.name, this.summoner.regionId)
    .pipe(
      tap((summoner) => this.matchHistory = summoner.matchHistory),
      concatMap((summoner: any) => {
        const observables = this.matchHistory
          .map(element => this.summ.getMatches(element.gameId));
        return forkJoin(observables)
      }),
      map(matchesArray => {
        // TODO: perform sorting
        return matchesArray;
      })
    ).subscribe(matchesArray => {

    });
}
```

I have omitted your sorting to keep the answer simple.

`matchesArray` is an array of the results mirroring the input `observables`.

Any sorting you want to perform could be performed in the `map` operator.

Any state you want to save out of the pipe can be done in a `tap` operator.

The key to combining observables is to remember that there is just one top-level subscriber. Observables can be combined in pretty much any way you can think of using pipe operators. This is why I recommend sticking to observables. They are more powerful than promises in complex scenarios.

Comment: I'm very thankful for that response. Now I understand how to use some rxjs operators! Now if I want to make another endpoint call and put that data inside matchesArray, do I have to make it inside 

 map(matchesArray => {
        // here
        return matchesArray;

And should I do the logic in the services?

Comment: If you want to make a single observable call, use another `concatMap` to run the observable. You can chain any number of sequential calls using a chain of `.pipe(concatMap(obs1), concatMap(obs2), concatMap(obs3), ... )`. If you want to run them in parallel, use `forkJoin`: `concatMap(() => forkJoin([obs1, obs2, obs3])`

Comment: Thank you again! :)